# Threads in c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

Windows Task Manager shows four threads for my simple C# Windows application. What are these for?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question...

Comment: There's Dasher, Dancer, Prancer and Vixen.

Comment: @Lasse I now have coffee all over my keyboard - cheers! :)

Comment: I edited this to sound less homeworky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Main thread
> 2. Debugger thread
> 3. Finalizer thread
> 4. GDI+ rendering thread

[Source](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/588402-do-nothing-winform-app-using-4-threads)

Answer (score 5):

There's good discussion on the topic on this thread:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/588402-do-nothing-winform-app-using-4-threads